# Memory Leak inspection with Windbg - Increase in heap size doesn't reflect in Heap detail

Tags: memory, malloc, windbg, heap-memory

I'm trying to detect a memory leak location for a certain process via Windbg, and have come across a strange problem.

Using windbg, I've created 2 memory dump snapshots - one before and one after the leak, that showed an increase of around 20MBs (detected via Performance Monitor - private bytes). it shows that there is indeed a similar size difference in one of the heaps before and after the leak (Used with the command **!heap -s**):

Before:

```
Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast 
                    (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
03940000 08000002   48740  35312  48740   4372   553     9    5     2d   LFH
    External fragmentation  12 % (553 free blocks)
03fb0000 08001002    7216   3596   7216   1286    75     4    8      0   LFH
    External fragmentation  35 % (75 free blocks)
05850000 08001002      60     16     60      5     2     1    0      0      
...
```

After:

```
Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast 
                    (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
03940000 08000002   64928  55120  64928   6232  1051    26    5     51   LFH
    External fragmentation  11 % (1051 free blocks)
03fb0000 08001002    7216   3596   7216   1236    73     4    8      0   LFH
    External fragmentation  34 % (73 free blocks)
05850000 08001002      60     16     60      5     2     1    0      0      
...
```

See the first Heap (**03940000**) - there is a difference in committed KBs of around 55120 - 35312 = 19808 KB = 20.2 MB.
However, when I inspected that heap with (**!heap -stat -h 03940000**), it displays the following for both dump files:

```
    size     #blocks    total     ( %) (percent of total busy bytes)
    3b32 1 - 3b32  (30.94)
    1d34 1 - 1d34  (15.27)
    880 1 - 880  (4.44)
    558 1 - 558  (2.79)
    220 1 - 220  (1.11)
    200 2 - 400  (2.09)
    158 1 - 158  (0.70)
    140 2 - 280  (1.31)
...(rest of the lines show no difference)
```

```
    size     #blocks    total     ( %) (percent of total busy bytes)
    3b32 1 - 3b32  (30.95)
    1d34 1 - 1d34  (15.27)
    880 1 - 880  (4.44)
    558 1 - 558  (2.79)
    220 1 - 220  (1.11)
    200 2 - 400  (2.09)
    158 1 - 158  (0.70)
    140 2 - 280  (1.31)
...(rest of the lines show no difference)
```

As you can see, there is hardly a difference between the two, despite the abovementioned 20MB size difference.
Is there an explanation for that?

**Note**: I have also inspected the Unmanaged memory using UMDH - there wasn't a noticeable size difference there.

Comment: "I have also inspected the Unmanaged memory" - what does that mean? Everything you analyze with `!heap` is unmanaged. `!heap` is not for .NET heaps.

Comment: VMMap - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/vmmap might also be worth a look to get a quick understanding.  Looking at either the number/size of allocations . You can "launch an trace a new process" and as you can configure symbols, you can get stack traces.